# Two way data binding using div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working with reactjs with redux.
i have created an editable `div` instead of `input` textfield but unable to receive the value.

So, in `input` textfield. There is a event named `onChange` which let you access the value type in `input` field. 
For example -

```
handlechange(e){
console.log(e.target.value);  //get the value of textbox then i further save it in state
}
render()
{
  return (
        <input
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}   
          value={this.state.msgText}
        </>
)}
```

But  I am using the editable div for same like this

```
<div
          role="textbox"
          ref={function(e){if(e != null) e.contentEditable=true;}}
          title="Type the text"
          //onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
          onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp.bind(this)}
        >
          {this.state.msgText}
        </div>
```

So , in handleKeyUp function

```
   handleKeyUp(e){
        var t = this;
        console.log('test');
        console.log(e);
        console.log(e.target.value);   // I have read ,i can only receive the keycode here,cannot receive value 
console.log(this.state.msgText);   //So i  should receive the value here but i am not
          if(e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //reset the state for clear the div
            t.setState({
              msgText: ""
            });
          }
        }
```

Once way of doing this is adding id on div like this -

```
<div
          id={"fc-"+ this.props.thread.uid + "-textbox"}
          role="textbox"
          className="ifc-chat-window-textbox-input"
          ref={function(e){if(e != null) e.contentEditable=true;}}
          title="Type the text"
          //onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
          //onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp.bind(this)}
        >
          {this.state.msgText}
        </div>
```

Then in componentDidMount function

```
    componentDidMount(){
         var t = this;
         var node = document.getElementById("fc-"+ this.props.thread.uid + "-textbox");
var value = node.textContent;   // I receive the value here
         node.onkeypress = function(event){
           t.setState({
             msgText: node.textContent
            });             });
           if(event.which == 13) {
             event.preventDefault();
             t.sendMsgObject(value , t.props.thread.uid, t.props.thread.name, t.props.thread.color, t.props.actions, t.props.user);
             //reset the state for clear input field
             t.setState({
               msgText: ""
             });
           }
```

All this works fine, but i dont think that is how things works in react. I am looking do to this without using id to div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have u tried something like that ?

```
var handleChange = function(event){
    this.setState({html: event.target.value});
}.bind(this);

return (<ContentEditable html={this.state.html} onChange={handleChange} />);
```

ContentEditable class

```
var ContentEditable = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <div 
            onInput={this.emitChange} 
            onBlur={this.emitChange}
            contentEditable
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.html}}></div>;
    },
    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps){
        return nextProps.html !== this.getDOMNode().innerHTML;
    },
    emitChange: function(){
        var html = this.getDOMNode().innerHTML;
        if (this.props.onChange && html !== this.lastHtml) {

            this.props.onChange({
                target: {
                    value: html
                }
            });
        }
        this.lastHtml = html;
    }
});
```

Comment: Problem is i am not using input text field, i am using editable div for same.

Comment: I am doing the same , i  have put like this <div>{this.state.value}</div> , then in keyUp function i am trying to access this.state.value , but it is giving undefined.